# EF Core - how to map custom type that is private

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, encapsulation, ef-fluent-api

I want to encapsulate the internals of my aggregate, but the way it is right now I could just call `Person.Address.Update()` and be able to modify that entity directly.

I'd like to make `Person.Address` a private field instead and not accessible from outside the aggregate root class. Could someone explain how to do the fluent API mapping for Entity Framework Core. Address goes in its own table (one to one relationship with Person).  I can't get it to work and don't want to be stuck with current design.

```
    public class Person : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }

    private Person() { }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, Address address)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Address = address;
    }

    public void UpdateAddress(string streetName)
    {
        Address.Update(streetName);
    }
}

public class Address : Entity
{
    public string StreetName { get; private set; }

    private Address() { }

    public Address(string streetName)
    {
        StreetName = streetName;
    }

    public void Update(string streetName)
    {
        StreetName = streetName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the way you've implemented a modification of the address via UpdateAddress is correct. You have your aggregate which has plenty, exposed business methods, through which you modify an entire state of the aggregate and surrounded entities. Maybe you could find a better method name than UpdateAddress because an "update" seems to be technical details, maybe: AssignAddres, LocateAtAddress, AttachAddress. Also from the UpdateAddress method there should be broadcasted business event e.g.: PersonaLocatedAtAddressEvent when the state of the aggregate (+inner entity) is changed.